# Peripheral uuid vs UIDevice identifierForVendor uuidString

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

Whats the difference between peripheral.identifier.uuidstring vs UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString. For context I am trying to set a unique id for each device in my DB and be able to call specific info based on the uid clicked from a bluetooth standpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to `peripheral.identifier.uuidstring` since I have no idea what `peripheral`'s type is :). But in any case, it sounds like `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` is the way you want to go. From the documentation for `identifierForVendor`:

> a UUID that may be used to uniquely identify the device, same across apps from a single vendor.

It will give you a unique, device-specific string. Even if a user deletes and reinstalls your app, the identifier will remain the same